# .htaccess Redirect 301 Issue

Tags: .htaccess

I am having an htaccess issue that I cannot seem to figure out.

On my site I have several pages that have /wiget/ in the url.

.com/wiget/
.com/wigeta/
.com/wigeb/
.com/wigetc/
.com/shop/wigeta/
.com/shop/wigetb/

In my htaccess file I am using the following:

- Redirect 301 /wiget/ http://www.site.com/content/wiget/
- Redirect 301 /wigeta/ http://www.site.com/content/wigeta/
- Redirect 301 /wigetb/ http://www.site.com/content/wigetb/
- Etc.

What is happening, is that every URL with /wiget/ /wigeta/ /wigetb/ in it is getting redirected incorrectly. For example, these urls:

- .com/shop/wiget/ is being sent to .com/shop/content/wiget/
- .com/shop/wigeta/ is being sent to .com/shop/content/wigeta/
- .com/shop/wigetb/ is being sent to .com/shop/content/wigetb/

What I want is only pages that have .com/wiget/ or .com/wigeta/ or .com/wigetb/ to be redirected to their .com/content/wiget{x}/ page

I am a rookie at htaccess and I cannot drum up the solution.

Comment: You should post your code.

Comment: I did, this is more or less my code with wiget replacing my keyword

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to specify that your url have to start with `/wiget/`

```
RewriteRule ^/wiget/ /content/wiget/ [L,R=301]
```